# Specifying initial directory for NSOpenPanel RunModal?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file-io

Seems like I must be overlooking something in documentation.

How do I specify a directory I want to start in when I use runModal with NSOpenPanel.

Some methods are deprecated in 10.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You set this using `setDirectoryURL` before displaying the panel with `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:`

It's specified in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSavePanel/beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:). `NSOpenPanel` subclasses `NSSavePanel` so you can use those methods as well.

Comment: Available in OS X v10.6.